# How to get email address from profile with MAPI

Tags: c++, mapi

I'm using MapiEx(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10881/MAPIEx-Extended-MAPI-Wrapper) to generate a mail.

I need the name and e-mail logged in the MAPI client to set as the sender in the e-mail.

The class CMAPIEx has the methods GetProfileName and GetProfileEmail, but to use those methods, I need to log in the MAPI with the user profile.

In the Login method of CMAPIEx I can pass the ProfileName, but I don't know what to pass.

My MAPI client is Outlook 2010, I tried to pass the e-mail or name that I set in my account, but nothing worked.

I looked the Login method in the CMAPIEx class and I found this:

```
DWORD dwFlags=MAPI_EXTENDED | MAPI_USE_DEFAULT | MAPI_NEW_SESSION;
if(bInitAsService) dwFlags|=MAPI_EXPLICIT_PROFILE | MAPI_NT_SERVICE;
return (MAPILogonEx(NULL, (LPTSTR)szProfileName, NULL, dwFlags, &m_pSession)==S_OK);
```

The third parameter of MAPILogonEx is the password and my account in Outlook has a password but in MAPILogonEx documentation(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815545.aspx) is said to let the password as NULL.

As I said in the second paragraph, I only need the name and e-mail logged in the MAPI client, if somebody knows what I'm doing wrong or some other way to get those information, please tell me.

Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not pass the profile name, you will end up with the default profile.
You can see the names of the existing profiles in Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles.
To enumarate the existing profiles programmatically, use IProfAdmin::GetProfileTable()